# React/Next.js: passed methods from parent to child gets executed in parent or child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, parent-child, next.js

I am a little bit confused, when I am passing a method defined in the parent component, that is changing the view of the parent component down to a child component (e.g to a button in the child component), and when I click the button on the child component, does the method from parent component gets executed in the parent class (and therefore, on the parent view) or on the child class (and then on the child view)?

lets say I want to display an alert message on the parent class when the button in the child class gets clicked, the alert message will get displayed on the parent I guess.

But is it also possible to pass a method defined in the parent down to the child and then change some views in the child component?

**EDIT:
I give an example for my problem:**

I have a component to render conditionally in Parent Class:
I pass the method onShowAlert to show an alert on parent component

```
if (this.state.alleAnzeigen.length > 0) {
      anzeigenListe = (
        <AnzeigenComponent 
          anzeigenArray={this.state.alleAnzeigen} 
          onClickAlert={this.onShowAlert}
          onButtonFinish={this.finishDocumentHandler}
        />
      )
```

In my AnzeigenComponent, I pass the method down to Anzeige Component,
first, I had onClickalert={() => props.onClickAlert} without the (), however, in my Parent the method was not executed then.

```
const anzeigenArray = (props) => {
    return props.anzeigenArray.map((anzeige,index) => (      
        <li className="mainList" key={anzeige.id} style={{padding: "10px"}} >
            <Anzeige 
              anzeige={anzeige} 
              key={anzeige.id}
              index={index}  
              onClickalert={() => props.onClickAlert()}
              onButtonfinish={() => props.onButtonFinish(anzeige,index)}
            />
        </li>
    ))
}

export default anzeigenArray;
```

my SubComponent "Anzeige" however, is a bigger Stateful Component Class:
when I click the button inside the singleAnzeige render function, I execute props.onClickalert()-> the method that I have passed down as props. However, the method doesn't do anything, unless I already execute that method with parentheses "()" in the component that I mentioned one above, I am just wondering, why is that so? Is there a limit of subcomponents where I can pass the method down only 2 levels or so, so that it still works?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DubletteComponent from '../components/DubletteComponent';

import { Button, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';


class Anzeige extends Component {     
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    singleAnzeige = (props) => {
        // let newText = this.htmlspecialchars_decode("71065 Sindelfingen71032 Böblingen75365 Calw72202 Nagold71083 Herrenberg71229 Leonberg");
        // console.log(newText);
        return (        
            <Row>                 
                <Col xs={12} md={2}><b>ID:</b> {props.anzeige.id}</Col>                
                <Col xs={12} md={3}><b>Titel:</b> {props.anzeige.title}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={3}><b>Institution:</b> {props.anzeige.institution}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={2}><b>Ort:</b> {props.anzeige.ort}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={2} className="linkButton">
                <a href={props.anzeige.link} target='_blank' className="anzeigeLink">Link</a> 
                <button  className="finishButton" onClick = {
                        () => {
                            if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to finish this document?')) {                        
                                props.onButtonfinish(props.anzeige,props.index);
                                props.onClickalert();
                            }
                        }                    
                    }>fertig</button> 
                </Col> 
                <style jsx>
                {`
                    p, a {          
                    } 
                    .linkButton {                                   
                        flexDirection: 'row',  
                        justifyContent: 'flex-end',   
                    }
                    .anzeigeLink {                    
                    }
                    .finishButton:hover {
                        background-color: green;
                    }
                    .finishButton {    
                        float: right;
                        border: 1px solid blue;
                        border-radius:  10px;
                        background-color: dark-green;             
                    }   
                    @media(max-width: 576px){
                        .finishButton {
                            float: none;
                            margin-right: 30px;
                            margin-left: 20px;
                        }
                    }                 
                `}
                </style>
            </Row>        
        );
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="anzeigeCard">        
                {this.singleAnzeige(this.props)}
                <DubletteComponent className="dublette" anzeigeID={this.props.anzeige.id} onSendDoubletten = {this.props.onClickAlert}/>
                <style jsx>
                    {`
                        .anzeigeCard {
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            padding: 10px;
                            margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                            border: 1px solid light-green;
                            width: 100%;
                            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
                        }
                    `}        
                </style>                 
            </div>       
        )
    }     
}

export default Anzeige
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit of subcomponents where I can pass the method down
>   only 2 levels or so, so that it still works?

There is no limit on how many levels you want to to pass your method as a prop,

```js
if (this.state.alleAnzeigen.length > 0) {
      anzeigenListe = (
        <AnzeigenComponent 
          anzeigenArray={this.state.alleAnzeigen} 
          onClickAlert={this.onShowAlert}
          onButtonFinish={this.finishDocumentHandler}
        />
      ) 
}
```

```js
const anzeigenArray = (props) => {
    return props.anzeigenArray.map((anzeige,index) => (      
        <li className="mainList" key={anzeige.id} style={{padding: "10px"}} >
            <Anzeige 
              anzeige={anzeige} 
              key={anzeige.id}
              index={index}  
              onClickalert={props.onClickAlert}
              onButtonfinish={props.onButtonFinish}
            />
        </li>
    ))
}

export default anzeigenArray;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DubletteComponent from '../components/DubletteComponent';

import { Button, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';


class Anzeige extends Component {     
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    singleAnzeige = (props) => {
        // let newText = this.htmlspecialchars_decode("71065 Sindelfingen71032 Böblingen75365 Calw72202 Nagold71083 Herrenberg71229 Leonberg");
        // console.log(newText);
        return (        
            <Row>                 
                <Col xs={12} md={2}><b>ID:</b> {props.anzeige.id}</Col>                
                <Col xs={12} md={3}><b>Titel:</b> {props.anzeige.title}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={3}><b>Institution:</b> {props.anzeige.institution}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={2}><b>Ort:</b> {props.anzeige.ort}</Col>
                <Col xs={12} md={2} className="linkButton">
                <a href={props.anzeige.link} target='_blank' className="anzeigeLink">Link</a> 

                // I couldn't verify this code, but I guess your "if" implementation may cause some error, so in order to help you investigate easier, I remove the "if" here 
                <button  className="finishButton" onClick = {
                        () => props.onButtonfinish(props.anzeige,props.index);                 
                    }>fertig</button> 
                </Col> 
                <style jsx>
                {`
                    p, a {          
                    } 
                    .linkButton {                                   
                        flexDirection: 'row',  
                        justifyContent: 'flex-end',   
                    }
                    .anzeigeLink {                    
                    }
                    .finishButton:hover {
                        background-color: green;
                    }
                    .finishButton {    
                        float: right;
                        border: 1px solid blue;
                        border-radius:  10px;
                        background-color: dark-green;             
                    }   
                    @media(max-width: 576px){
                        .finishButton {
                            float: none;
                            margin-right: 30px;
                            margin-left: 20px;
                        }
                    }                 
                `}
                </style>
            </Row>        
        );
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="anzeigeCard">        
                {this.singleAnzeige(this.props)}
                <DubletteComponent className="dublette" anzeigeID={this.props.anzeige.id} onSendDoubletten = {this.props.onClickAlert}/>
                <style jsx>
                    {`
                        .anzeigeCard {
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            padding: 10px;
                            margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                            border: 1px solid light-green;
                            width: 100%;
                            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
                        }
                    `}        
                </style>                 
            </div>       
        )
    }     
}

export default Anzeige
```

Comment: you mean    onClickAlert={this.onShowAlert}
          onButtonFinish={this.finishDocumentHandler} ? but thats exactly the problem I was wondering about, because if I do it like that, nothing happens when I execute the button, the alarm is not showing up. But when I execute the function (), the alarm shows up, and I don't understand why this is..

Comment: I'm not sure why your code didn't work. U also need to watch out your case sensitive variables. 

Here is an easy example of how u should do: https://codepen.io/darrylrn/pen/byeLed, first link will show an alert, second link will print props in console.